# Spring Cloud DataFlow local Server not importing the new custom source for Tailing File

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to write a custom source for "Tailing" and I used the snippets from spring samples to write that code. Here is the actual code,

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TailSourceProperties.class)
public class TailSourceConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private TailSourceProperties properties;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TailSourceConfiguration.class); 

    @Autowired
    Source source;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow tailFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from((MessageProducers p) ->p.tail(new File(properties.getFilename())).delay(500).end(false).autoStartup(true)).channel(source.output()).get();
    }
}
```

And the Properties file is,

```
@ConfigurationProperties("tail")
public class TailSourceProperties {

    /**
     * The file name to tail
     */
    @Value("#{ systemProperties['tail.file'] ?: '/tmp/tailfile.log'}")
    private String filename;

     /**
     * the native options to be used in conjunction with the tail command eg. -F -n 0 etc.
     */
    @Value("#{ systemProperties['tail.nativeoptions'] ?: '-F -n 0'}")
    private String nativeOptions;

    public String getNativeOptions() {
        return nativeOptions;
    }

    public void setNativeOptions(String nativeOptions) {
        this.nativeOptions = nativeOptions;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

}
```

Now when I run a junit test with this code, using the below junit testcase it works just fine.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TailSourceApplication.class)
@DirtiesContext
public abstract class TailSourceTests {


    @Autowired
    protected Source source;

    @Autowired
    protected MessageCollector messageCollector;


    @IntegrationTest({})
    public static class payloadTest extends TailSourceTests {

        @Test
        public void otherTest() throws Exception
        {
            Message<?> received= messageCollector.forChannel(source.output()).poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("Received ="+received);
        }

        @Test
        public void testSimpleFile() throws Exception {
            int i = messageCollector.forChannel(source.output()).size();
            System.out.println("Size = +"+i);
            Message<?> received= messageCollector.forChannel(source.output()).poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            for (Iterator<Message<?>> iter = messageCollector.forChannel(source.output()).iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
                    {
                System.out.println("value ="+iter.next().getPayload());
                    }
            System.out.println("RECEIVED = "+received);
            Assert.notNull(received);
        }
    }


    @SpringBootApplication
    static class TailSourceApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(TailSourceApplication.class, args);
        }

    }

}
```

I do see the default file contents in the console when I run the junit test.

Now I am facing two issues with this when I try to bundle it in a jar and deploy it to the local spring cloud dataflow server with versions :

- spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
- spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar

The shell jar version I am using is,

- spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar

the issues I am facing are :

1. The source type gets deployed successfully and also shows up in the app list but the app properties info does not show up when I run the ***app info source:tail***, please check the screenshot below.

[Screenshot of the shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PAxt.png)

The jar structure is exactly similar to the File source boot jar and is constructed using the Spring's Maven wrapper. the json properties file with the metadata is also generated according to the expectation and is present in the META_INF in the bundled spring source jar.

2. The source itself does not work.
   When I try to use this new tail source with log sink it never works.

Finally, I do know that it might not work on a cloud server but the plan is it run it on a local server-local dataflow server. I also know know I can try with spring integration framework itself but it is an external request to accomplish this through spring cloud Dataflow.

Any help is deeply appreciated, and my request goes out to Artem (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756547/artem-bilan), Gary(https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell) and everyone else from all the communities. Have a good one thanks in advance for your comments and feedback !

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 1.4.x? If yes, there's a known issue wrt property whitelisting support that we have in SCDF. This would impact `app info source:tail` experience. We are exploring options to fix the constrain through [#748](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/748). Also, the `local-server` is strictly only recommended for development needs. If you're to move this workload to production, you'd have to use Cloud Foundry or other server implementations.

Comment: The source looks fine; if the problem is not the one @SabbyAnandan mentioned, the first step is to turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` and compare the bean wiring between the working test and the deployer.

Comment: @Sabby yes, I am using spring boot 1.4 but I am following the catch highlighted in the [link] http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-dataflow-register-apps.html#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting . I am using the 

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>  1
    </plugin>
to rewrap it in a 1.3.x compatible jar! not sure if the server itself is built with 1.4.x though

Answer (score 1):

First of all thank for invitation to review your work :).

Secondly, that is a great work and I insist to contribute it back to the Framework. We have such a module in Spring XD, I'm not sure what stops us to extend Spring Cloud Stream Apps to `tail` as well. So, feel free to fill out the [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/issues) on the matter and PR the solution!

Now, I think that you have to add `spring-configuration-metadata-whitelist.properties` file into `META-INF` of your jar.

The content for you must be something like this:

```
configuration-properties.classes=[THE_PACKAGE_TO_CLASS].TailSourceProperties
```

Also it isn't going to work as is without proper Binder assembling.

You have to add `spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit-1.0.0.RELEASE` dependency to your project to build the target uber jar with RabbitMQ Binder. Or `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` if that is your case.

See more info in the Spring Cloud Stream App Starters Stream [README](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters).

Comment: honored to receive yours,Russel's and Sabby feedback in such a short notice. 
yes, i already have the properties file and below are the contents,

`configuration-classes=com.xxx.spring.tail.source.TailSourceProperties, \
  org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.trigger.TriggerPropertiesMaxMessagesDefaultUnlimited
`
I initially had only the TailSourceProperties one but when it never worked i felt compelled to add the trigger one too dont know why ! and dont ask why !

Comment: I also checked the source's pom and this is what I have there,
  `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
  </dependency>`
Do you think there something more that I am missing ?

Comment: You don't need `Trigger` because `FileTailingMessageProducerSupport` isn't `MessageSource`. It's event-driven producer. So,your `TailSourceP‌​roperties` is enough. Pay attention, my property is `configuration-properties.classes` and yours `configuration-classes`. Try to run the result jar manually, without Data Flow.

Comment: Also noticed that when I initiate a stream like 

`stream create tail --definition "tail | log --level=ALL" --deploy`

I do see the kafka queue getting created
`[root@localhost bin]# ./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
tail.tail
`
created. So not sure :( !

Comment: How about to share the final jar somewhere?

Comment: yes you are right. i have the wrong value but it is in the [link] http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-dataflow-register-apps.html#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting . if configuration-classes is wrong please kindly correct the documentation as well. I am trying the jar with the changed properties.

Comment: yes I can you kindly share your email or something ? I am sorry but I cannot upload it to public ...some restrictions... hope you can understand !!!

Comment: OK. Sabby says that you are in contact with him. So, you can send the jar to him and he will resend to me :).